# How can I add a custom filter to my Twig templates inside of Slim?

Tags: php, twig, slim

Using the example from http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-an-extension: within my main `Slim` file that creates the view:

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter( 'stripslashes', function ( $string ) { 
    return stripslashes( $string );
});

$loader = new \Twig_Loader_String();
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter($filter);

$app->view($twig);

$app->view()->setData( array(
    'nav' => $nav,
    'sidenav' => $sidenav,
));
```

Results in: `Call to undefined method Twig_Environment::appendData()`.

Tried in various ways such as this:

```
$app->view(new \Slim\Views\Twig());
$app->view->parserExtensions = array(
    new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(),
);

$app->view->addFilter($filter);
```

but I'm just not understanding how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 11):

For Slim 3, things have changed.  It can be done in one line:

```
$view->getEnvironment()->addFilter($filter);
```

But that isn't particularly useful without context, so here is a full sample, based on the example provided at the Slim Framework Website: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html

This code demonstrates adding a filter to encode text with rot13

```
<?php
// Create app
$app = new \Slim\App();

// Get container
$container = $app->getContainer();

// Register component on container
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
   $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('path/to/templates', [
       'cache' => 'path/to/cache'
    ]);
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $container['router'],
        $container['request']->getUri()
    ));

    $filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('rot13', function ($string) {
        return str_rot13($string);
    });

    $view->getEnvironment()->addFilter($filter);

    return $view;
};

// Render Twig template in route
$app->get('/rot13/{text}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $this->view->render($response, 'rot13.html', [
        'name' => $args['text']
    ]);
})->setName('rot13');

// Run app
$app->run();
```

And the html file rot13.html contains:

```
{{text|rot13}}
```

Point your browser at *yourservername*/rot13/pineapple and you should see

```
cvarnccyr
```

Comment: I get this error  

`Type: Error
Message: Class 'Twig_SimpleFilter' not found
File: D:\xampp\htdocs\slim_tutorial\home\linearct\checkin\bootstrap\containers.php
Line: 13`  What dependencies do I need to install? I tried `twig/extensions` and it was telling me to remove  twig/twig v3.0.0

Answer (score 4):

Ah. Just needed this two liner:

```
$twig = $app->view->getInstance();
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```