# How to prevent twig from auto escaping Japanese characters?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twig, momentjs

I am trying to display product's arrival date. I'm using `moment.js` to format `YYYY/MM/DD`date string to Japanese local string. My javascript code is included in a `twig` file:

```
<script>
        moment.locale('ja');
        let updateArrivalDate = function() {
            $('.arrival-date').each(function() {
                let $this = $(this);
                $selectDate = $this.next().next().find('select').eq(0);
                $selectTime = $this.next().next().find('select').eq(1);
                var text = $selectDate.val();
                var date = moment(text, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
                if (date.isValid()) {
                    $this.text(date.format('{{ 'YYYY年M月D日 (dd)'|raw }}'))
                }
            });
        };
        $(document).ready(function() {
          updateArrivalDate();
            $('select').on('change', function() {
                updateArrivalDate();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

As you can see, I used `raw` filter to prevent twig from escaping Japanese characters. Nevertheless, twig escapes special characters anyway and the text is garbled:

[image: garbled Japanese characters due to twig auto-escaping]

Of course, it would be solved if I moved the above snippet to an external file. But seriously, is there not a way to stop twig escaping Japanese characters? Why is `raw` filter **not** working?

Comment: Have you tried to start the html page with `<html lang="ja">` as well instead of `<html>`? Pehrpahs using that tag will allow the browser to render the kanji better. As I see the problem is that the Kanji is not encoded properly. So that's I suggest this approach. Also try using a `<meta charset="UTF-8"\>` tag as well in order further to enforce the browser to use this encoding as well.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to help if you provided the HTML so it can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import moment `ja` locale from the cdn (or from npm/yarm installed package) as seen in https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/

If you use a cdn hosted js then use the following code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/ja.js" integrity="sha256-CFWtR1hGN/5Vc+kcJkqeMFND0g6gFFZdnSqUtdL7WOQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then instead of:

```
 $this.text(date.format('{{ 'YYYY年M月D日 (dd)'|raw }}'))
```

Use:

```
 var date = moment(text, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
 $this.html(date.locale('ja').format('LL (dd)'))
```

And remove the:

```
        moment.locale('ja');
```

line

So your script will be:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/ja.js" integrity="sha256-CFWtR1hGN/5Vc+kcJkqeMFND0g6gFFZdnSqUtdL7WOQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
        let updateArrivalDate = function() {
            $('.arrival-date').each(function() {
                let $this = $(this);
                $selectDate = $this.next().next().find('select').eq(0);
                $selectTime = $this.next().next().find('select').eq(1);
                let text = $selectDate.val();
                let date = moment(text, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
                if (date.isValid()) {
                    $this.text(date.locale('ja').format('LL (dd)'))
                }
            });
        };
        $(document).ready(function() {
          updateArrivalDate();
            $('select').on('change', function() {
                updateArrivalDate();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Consult the example bellow containing only the formating regarding the language:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#date").html(moment().locale('ja').format('LL (dd)'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/ja.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="date"></div>
```

So you let moment to format the date and avoid any complexity with js/twig. Just keep it simple and let the js to do its job instead of mixing them all together.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but I'm already using `moment.js` with locale. As you can see, the day of the week is displayed correctly(`dd` format).

Comment: OK, `LL (dd)` format works perfectly. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Also you can use twig itself via a custom filter itself as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/q/27714854/4706711 and just make a japaneese date formatter that does the formatting itself, though seems like a waste of server resources for something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change the code like that :

```
$this.text(date.format('{{ "YYYY年M月D日 (dd)"|json_encode()|raw }}'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but not exactly. It outputs quotation mark(`"`) as well. So I had to replace them like this: `$this.text((date.format('{{ 'YYYY年M月D日 (dd)'|json_encode()|raw }}')).replace(/"/g, ''));` It doesn't look so beautiful. I think @DimitriosDesyllas 's answer is more reasonable.